# Python for ArcGIS - Calculate field with a text field as parameter

Tags: python, field, arcgis, arcpy

I am trying to create and calculate a field called Score in an attribute table. Score would depend on two other fields, Width and Category. Width contains integer values, Category contains text. The Score field should assign a number of points based on the values of these two fields.

I was able to write a Python script assign values to SCORE based on the value of Width. However, once I tried to add Category as a parameter, I kept getting error messages saying that the parameters are not valid.

The code below worked (Width only):

```
expression = "getClass(float(!Width!))"
    codeblock = """def getClass(wd):
        if wd<=450:
            return 1
        elif wd>450 and wd<900:
            return 2
        else:
            return 3"""
 arcpy.AddField_management("featurelayer", "Score", "SHORT")
```

This code includes Category as a parameter and does not work:

```
expression = "getClass(!Width!,!Category!)"
codeblock = """def getClass(wd,cat):
    if wd<=35:
        return 1
    elif wd<90 and cat=='RED':
        return 2
    else:
        return 3"""

arcpy.AddField_management("featurelayer", "Score", "SHORT")
```

Thank you!

***I did try converting the two parameters in the second code - I tried float() for both, as well as str() for Category since it is a text field. Neither one worked, and the error messages were not very specific: "failed to execute getClass()"

***The Category field is completely populated (either 'RED' or 'BLUE')

Comment: I noticed expression originally converted to float().  Does adding that function to !Width! and !Category! in the new code have any impact?

Comment: are all of your Category records populated?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. All of the category records are populated. I tried adding float() to width and str() to category (because it is text); that didn't work either.

Comment: Are you sure the Category-field is named like that? Maybe misspelled, case-sensitive, or you're using an alias instead of the real field name?  What happens, if you use default values on your getClass function?  Like `def getClass(wd=0,cat=''):`  can you try the first version but this time with only Category? Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Using the expression and codeblock method is necessary within ArcMap's Field Calculator, but not when writing a Python script.

[Try an UpdateCursor instead.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000) It is easier to read, and tends to be easier to debug as a result.

```
arcpy.AddField_management("featurelayer", "Score", "SHORT")

updateFields = ["Width", "Category", "Score"]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("featurelayer", updateFields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] <= 35:
            row[2] = 1
        elif row[0] < 90 and row[1] == 'RED':
            row[2] = 2
        else:
            row[2] = 3
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```